# getParameter in Servlet from form in JSP

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp with a form

```html
<form action="Login" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form><!-- form -->
```

In the login Servlet I do the next:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
```

The problem is the pass and email is always null, I don't know why.

Comment: Use `name` rather than `id` for your `input`s.

Answer (score 4):

Because you get parameters by `name`. Try to put this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" id="email" name="email" />
```

And you'll get the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <form action="Login" method="post">
<h1>Login</h1>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required=""  name="password" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</div>
</form>
```

---

```
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
```

Answer (score 0):

jsp code

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="loginForm" method="post" >  
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <input type="password" name="password" required="">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" required>
</form>
</body>
```

servlet code

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    //System.out.print(username);
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    //System.out.print(password);

    if (//handle ur logic) {//call validate function in UserValidate.java
        //System.out.println("validate true");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        //System.out.println("validate false");
        out.print("<p style=\"color:blue\">Invalid Username Password</p>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

    out.close();

}
```

in here you have to create a session and setAttribute("username",username).
i think u get some idea.